# PyPi deployment from Travis CI: Invalid or non-existent authentication

Tags: pip, travis-ci, pypi

When deploying via Travis CI to PyPi I get the following error:

`HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/`

I've followed the Travis CI documentation for [pypi deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pypi/) and have setup my PyPI username and password, with the latter encrypted per the [password encryption docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys#note-on-escaping-certain-symbols). The password does not have any escape-worthy characters but I've tried escaping all characters regardless.

Nothing seems to work, any advice?

The relevant section of the Travis CI config is:

```
- provider: pypi
  on:
    branch: master
    tags: true
  user: "<<username>>"
  password:
    secure: "<<encrypted password>>"
  distributions: "sdist bdist_wheel"
  skip_existing: true
```

### EDIT

Before Travis runs `preparing deploy` and `deploying the application` it appears to authenticate successfully. Yet when it finishes the upload it kicks up the 403 invalid auth error:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
...
Authenticated as <<username>>
Preparing deploy
...
Deploying application
...
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading example-package-py3-none-any.whl
100%|██████████| 41.0k/41.0k [00:00<00:00, 90.3kB/s]
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Comment: Fix `skip-existing` -> `skip_existing`.

Comment: @phd, thanks, have updated the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting `travis-ci` support they noted that the repository first existed against `travis-ci.org` as opposed to `travis-ci.com`. This created issues for the authentication.

The solution was to explicitly run `travis encrypt` against `travis-ci.com`:

```
travis encrypt <<password>> --com --debug
```

The debug flag is obviously optional, and provides some added info in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Password should be only alphanumeric characters.

Lose "server" in config.

```
server: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
```

Comment: I assume you meant "use" instead of "lose": Tried setting the server upload URL explicitly and it still throws error.